# slow database insertion slowness sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database

At some costumer we have a really slow insertion to the database (three time slower then normal).
I cannot see the reason why it happening. Checked the network and it seems to be ok.

Any suggestions what can be wrong with the db here ? and how i can check it  ?

We are using sql server 2005.

thanks .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a combination of perfmon and [sql profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(v=sql.80).aspx) could help you identify the issues.

Perfmon can use a series of SQL specific monitors [per the microsoft technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx)  But I'd also suggest looking at your disk performance, not to mention looking into the sql specific performance using [DBCC per a few resources out there.](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/dhite/archive/2007/03/24/monitoring-sql-2005-performance-statistics-with-the-dbcc-sqlperf-command.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an issue with storage at that client.  IO is one of the biggest contributing factors to SQL Server performance (or lack thereof).  What is your storage configuration at that client?

Have a look through these articles.  There are also a ton more with regards to storage configuration best practices for SQL Server.

- [**Storage Top 10 Best Practices**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966534.aspx)
- [**Storage and SQL Server capacity planning and configuration**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298801.aspx) (Written for SharePoint but focusing on the SQL backend)
- [**SAN Implementation and Tuning**](http://www.brentozar.com/consulting-services/san-implementation-tuning/) (if you're using a SAN)

Answer (score 1):

Profile an insertion and get the query execution plan.

Might be updating running triggers, or updating excessive number of indexes.